# Not able to populate listview from firebase in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, firebase-realtime-database

I am creating an app that deals with getting data from firebase and inserting it into a fragment list whenever the data changes 
I created a method in the fragment activity

```
public void send(String data)
{
mylist.add(data);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

I tried to add the listener in the onStart() of the main activity which sends the data to the fragment

```
@Override 
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot data)
{
baby = data.getValue(String.class);
frag.send(baby);
}
```

I didn't get any error but no data was inserted into the fragment list
I would like to if there is anything i am not doing correctly or is there a better approach to it
I referenced the node like this

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    toolbar();
     Array= 
     FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Array");
     child = Array.child("2");
}
```

Comment: Please share the lines where you add the data to the database.

Comment: Since I was just testing I didn't add it programatically i added the data on firebase directly and I tried to retrieve it in onStart() of main activity and I sent it to the fragment list by calling the send() which either adds the data or updates it

Comment: Can you post how are you referencing your listener to the desired node.

Comment: I referenced the node using the method listed on firebase documentation